# htaccess RewriteRule loading two page at the same time

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have this link and extended part of it,

`user.php?u=Adam`

`user.php?u=Adam&p=posts`

I cleaned it with this rewriterule

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule ^user/(\w+)/(\w+)$ ./user.php?name=$1&p=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^user/(\w+)$ ./user.php?name=$1 [NC,L]
```

these links now is working

`user/Adam`

`user/Adam/posts`

the problem is whenever I load `user/Adam/posts` it loads `user/Adam` with it, it shows two pages first `user/Adam/posts` then after scrolling down it shows `user/Adam`.
because `user/Adam` is part of `user/Adam/posts`.

but how to do I condition it to do one not the other.

Comment: I think it doesn't come from your rewrite rules, but from your PHP script. Could you post a part of it?

Comment: You may load two pages into a browser window, but not with rewrite rules, the cause may be somewhere else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it doesn't come from your rewrite rules, but from your PHP script.

By browsing to `/user/Adam/posts` :

```
var_dump($_GET) ; // array(2) { ["name"]=> string(4) "Adam" ["p"]=> string(5) "posts" }
```

So, in your PHP script, you should use :

```
if (isset($_GET['name']) && isset($_GET['p'])) {
    // do something
}
elseif (isset($_GET['name'])) {
    // do something else 
}
```

or

```
if (isset($_GET['name'])) {
    if (isset($_GET['p'])) {
        // do something
    }
    else {
       // do something else 
    }
}
```

Comment: it was off javscript when loading pages of link like "/include/...." not like "http://website/include"